# access struts bean properties in scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, struts, el, scriptlet

I've a struts form bean which have several properties and based on those properties I need to create a string url.

e.g., My bean name is `formBean` and some properties are `name`, `email`, `mobile` and so on.

And the url will contain these form properties as query parameters. For this I've been trying using scriptlet as:

```
<%! String url = "http://somewebsite.com/request.jsp?param1=" + {accessing formBean.name} %>
<a href="<%= url %>">URL</a>
```

But the problem I'm facing is to access the `bean` properties in scriptlet as both can not be used in same context.
What could be the better approach for same? Suggestions are also appreciated.

Comment: try formBean.getName() it may give you value of name in scriptlet

Comment: @NiravPrajapati: as `formBean` is a struts bean so it is not available in `jsp` to directly access it as `formBean.getName()`. There is an error `cannot be resolve or not a field`

Comment: do you use MVC method to set and get the form bean data/ value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the below code:

```
<a href="http://somewebsite.com/request.jsp?name=${formBean.name}&mobile=${formBean.mobile}">URL</a>
```